# Facebook dialog with "sharing as" a la sharer.php

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, fb.ui

Is there any way to use javascript sdk (FB.ui) and give the option to share as a page that one manages? You can do it with sharer.php, but I want to use FB.ui for a range of reasons, namely, this is the single feature of sharer.php that I prefer.

The share dialog only allows option to switch user ( not to post as a businesss page )

[image: only option to switch user]

Sharer.php allows to post as business page, but is otherwise lacking.]

[image: sharer.php allows choosing to post as a business page]

When logged in as business page, opening feed dialog
[image: logged in as business page, opening feed dialog]

Answer (score 0):

Would it be possible for you to use the [Feed Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog/v2.3) instead? That dialog accepts a `from` parameter, where you can set the Page ID.

Comment: Feed Dialog seems to invite you to switch to your user account. I could set the page id dynamically, but that requires gathring the page ID in the first place, and this is for outside users. thanks for idea. Editing original post to include screenshot of Feed Dialog when logged in as page